# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'x_win' ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help me I have tried so much things but this doesn't work...
I'm beginner  in POO (my code is so ugly wtf) and i don't understand why my code doesn't work ...
I give you **a code which works** and **a code which doesn't work** while they used the same attribute ...

this code works:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
root = Tk()
x = 0
y = 0
def move_window(event):
    # global x, y
    print(x, y)
    root.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root - x, event.y_root - y))

root.overrideredirect(True) # turns off title bar, geometry
root.geometry('400x200+200+200') # set new geometry

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='white', relief='raised', bd=2)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy)

# a canvas for the main area of the window
window = Canvas(root, bg='black')

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# bind title bar motion to the move window function
def setxy(event):
    global x,y
    x=event.x_root - root.winfo_x()
    y=event.y_root - root.winfo_y()
    # print(x,y)
    return x,y;
title_bar.bind('<1>',setxy)

title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)

root.mainloop()
```

**and this one doesn't  :**

```
import os 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

win = tk.Tk()
win.overrideredirect(1)





# def realcenter( o, w, h ) ->'o(w,h) centered on screen':
#     x = o.winfo_screenwidth( ) - w
#     y = o.winfo_screenheight( ) - h
#     o.geometry( f'{w}x{h}+{int( x/2 )}+{int( y/2 )}' )

# def restore( ev ):
#     win.overrideredirect( 0 )

# def unrestore( ev ):
#     win.overrideredirect( 1 )

# win.geometry( '500x525' )
# realcenter( win, 500, 525)

# win.update_idletasks()

# win.overrideredirect( 1 )

# win.bind( '<F1>', restore )
# win.bind( '<F2>', unrestore )

font1 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 15)
font3 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 8, weight = 'bold')
font2 = font.Font(family = 'Helvetica', size = 20, weight = 'bold')

def aaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
    Ecrire('',Light)

def aaaa(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#C47ED6")
    Ecrire('',Dark)

def strl(list):
    
        list ="".join(list)
        return list



# menubar = Menu(win)
# win.config(menu=menubar)
# menufichier = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
# menubar.add_cascade(label="Theme", menu=menufichier) 
# menufichier.add_command(label=" Dark mode",font = font3,command =lambda: aaa('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F"))
# menufichier.add_command(label=" Light mode",font = font3,command =lambda: aaaa('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#C47ED6"))
 
pixel = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

a =95
b =95

theme = 0
t = 0

ecrit = []
nombre_de_multdiv = 0
nombre_de_sous_add = 0

def Del(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[-1]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Del_all(self):
    global ecrit
    del ecrit[:]
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)

def Ecrire(symbole,self):

    ecrit.append(symbole)
    affichage = strl(ecrit)
    self.label1['text'] = affichage
    self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)


def Ecrire_Resulat(valeur,self):
    valeur = strl(valeur)
    self.label1['text'] = valeur

def Calcul(self):
    global nombre_de_multdiv
    global nombre_de_sous_add

    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '/' or ecrit[i] == '*':
            nombre_de_multdiv +=1
    for i in range(len(ecrit)):
        if ecrit[i]  == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':
            nombre_de_sous_add +=1

    for i in range(nombre_de_multdiv):

        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '*' or ecrit[i] == '/':

                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):

                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':

                        nb +=1

                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                for i in range(numero):

                    i = -i

                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':

                        nbb -=1

                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='*':
                    resultat = nombre1 * nombre2

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(resultat))


                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 / nombre1

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(resultat))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]
                for i in range(len(resultat)):

                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])
                    
                break

    for i in range(nombre_de_sous_add):

        for i in range(len(ecrit)):
            if ecrit[i] == '+' or ecrit[i] == '-':

                numero = i
                nb = i
                nbb = i

                for i in range(len(ecrit)-numero-1):


                    if ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '/' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '*' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '+' and ecrit[i+1 + numero] != '-':

                        nb +=1

                    elif ecrit[i+1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i+1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                for i in range(numero):

                    i = -i

                    if ecrit[i-1+numero] != '/' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '*' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '+' and ecrit[i-1+numero] != '-':

                        nbb -=1

                    elif ecrit[i-1+numero] == '/' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '*' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '+' or ecrit[i-1+numero] == '-':

                        break 

                nombre1 = "".join(ecrit[numero+1:nb+1])
                nombre1 = float(nombre1)
                nombre2 = "".join(ecrit[nbb:numero])
                nombre2 = float(nombre2)

                if ecrit[numero] =='+':
                    resultat = nombre1 + nombre2

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(resultat))


                else:
                    resultat = nombre2 - nombre1

                    if resultat == int(resultat):
                        resultat = int(resultat)

                    resultat = list(str(resultat))

                del ecrit[nbb:nb+1]

                for i in range(len(resultat)):

                    ecrit.insert(nbb+i,resultat[i])

                break
    Ecrire_Resulat(ecrit,self)


class Theme():

    def move_window(self,event):
        # global x, y
        print(self.x, self.y)
        win.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_win - self.x, event.y_win - self.y))

    def set_xy(self,event):

        self.x=event.x_win - win.winfo_x()
        self.y=event.y_win - win.winfo_y()
        # print(x,y)
        return self.x,self.y;

    def boutontheme(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf)
        if self.t == 0:
            Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")
            self.t = 1
        else:
            Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
            self.t = 0



    def openmenu(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):
        if self.ouvert == False:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colore)
            if self.t == 0:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
            else:
                self.b_theme_dark = tk.Button(win,state=NORMAL, text = 'Dark theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
                self.b_theme_light = tk.Button(win,state=DISABLED, text = 'Light theme',font = font3,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 70,activebackground =colore,bg =colora,fg = colord,command = lambda: self.boutontheme(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
            
            self.b_theme_dark.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 25)
            self.b_theme_light.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 45) 
            self.ouvert = True
            return;

        if self.ouvert == True:
            self.b_theme.config(bg = colorb)
            self.b_theme_dark.destroy()
            self.b_theme_light.destroy()
            self.ouvert = False 
            return;


    # def closemenu(self):
    #   self.b_theme_dark.forget()
    #   self.b_theme_light.forget()

    #   ouvert = False 


    def __init__(self,colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf):

        
        if colora == '#18181F':
            self.t = 0
        else:
            self.t = 1

        self.ouvert = False
        self.x = 0
        self.y=0

        #creation menu

        self.canvas_menu = Canvas(win, width =500, height =25, bg = colora, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit = Canvas(bg = colora,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.exit.create_oval(0,0,20,20, fill= colore,width = 0)
        self.exit.create_text(10, 10, text="x", fill = colord, font= font3)
        self.exit.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: win.destroy())

        #affichage menu

        self.exit.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 475, y = 2)
        self.canvas_menu.grid(row = 0,column = 0, columnspan = 5)

        #creation des canvas

        self.canvas_screen = Canvas(win, width =500, height =100, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_num = Canvas(win, width =300, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas_keyb_op = Canvas(win, width =200, height =400, bg =colorb,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)

        #affchage des canvas

        self.canvas_screen.grid(row = 1,column = 0, columnspan = 5)
        self.canvas_keyb_num.grid(row = 2,column = 0, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 4)
        self.canvas_keyb_op.grid(row = 2,column = 3, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 4)

        # creation des boutons

        self.b1 = Button(win, text ='1',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('1',self))
        self.b2 = Button(win, text ='2',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('2',self))
        self.b3 = Button(win, text ='3',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('3',self))
        self.b4 = Button(win, text ='4',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('4',self))
        self.b5 = Button(win, text ='5',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('5',self))
        self.b6 = Button(win, text ='6',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('6',self))
        self.b7 = Button(win, text ='7',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('7',self))
        self.b8 = Button(win, text ='8',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('8',self))
        self.b9 = Button(win, text ='9',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('9',self))
        self.b_point = Button(win, text ='.',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('.',self))
        self.b0 = Button(win, text ='0',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('0',self))
        
        self.b_plus = Button(win, text ='+',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('+',self))
        self.b_moins = Button(win, text ='-',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('-',self))
        self.b_fois = Button(win, text ='*',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('*',self))
        self.b_diviser = Button(win, text ='/',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Ecrire('/',self))
        self.b_del = Button(win, text ='DEL',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del(self))
        self.b_del_all = Button(win, text ='CE',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colora,activebackground =colorc,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = b ,font = font1,command=lambda: Del_all(self))
        self.b_egale = Button(win, text ='=',borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = colore,activebackground =colorf,foreground=colord,compound="c",image = pixel,height = a,width = 295 ,font = font1,command= lambda: Calcul(self))

        #affichage des nombres

        #colone 1

        self.b7.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.b4.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        self.b1.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
        self.b_point.grid(column = 0, row = 5)

        #colone 2

        self.b8.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.b5.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.b2.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
        self.b0.grid(column = 1, row = 5)

        #colone 3

        self.b9.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.b6.grid(column = 2, row = 3)
        self.b3.grid(column = 2, row = 4)

        #operateurs

        self.b_plus.grid(column = 3, row = 2)
        self.b_moins.grid(column = 4, row = 2)
        self.b_fois.grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        self.b_diviser.grid(column = 4, row = 3)
        self.b_del.grid(column = 3, row = 4)
        self.b_del_all.grid(column = 4, row = 4)
        self.b_egale.grid(column = 2, row = 5,columnspan = 3)

        #ecriture

        self.label1 = tk.Label(win, text = '', justify = tk.RIGHT,font = font2,bg =colorb,fg = colord)
        self.label1.place(anchor = 'e', x = 450, y = 75)
        self.b_theme = tk.Button(win, text = 'Themes',font = font3,bg =colorb,fg = colord,borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,compound="c",image = pixel,height = 20,width = 50,activebackground =colore,command= lambda: self.openmenu(colora, colorb, colorc, colord, colore, colorf))
        self.b_theme.place(anchor = 'nw', x = 5, y = 2)

        self.canvas_menu.bind('<1>', self.set_xy)

        # bind title bar motion to the move window function

        self.canvas_menu.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_window)

        # b_theme_dark.config(bg =colorb,fg = colord, activebackground =colore)
        # b_theme_light.config(bg =colorb,fg = colord, activebackground =colore)

        # menufichier.config(activebackground = colorc,bg = colora,fg = colord)


if theme == 0:
    Dark = Theme('#18181F','#0C0C0F',"#505063",'#D1DDFF','#D12319',"#D1665F")
else:
    Light = Theme('#F1EDF5','#D1D2E8',"#EDD5EB",'#323133','#6F2EB0',"#915ec4")

win.title('calculator')






#pour un future menu 

# bouton.config(state=DISABLED)
# bouton.config(state=NORMAL)

win.resizable(height=False,width=False)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think it should be ```event.x_root``` or simply ```x```

Comment: No where in the first code example for the function `move_window` do you call the method `move_window` That is why you get an error in the second example.

Comment: The error is telling you precisely what is wrong.  You're trying to reference an attribute named `x_win`, but the object doesn't have it. There's no documentation of that object ever having that attribute. Why do you think it does, and what do you think it's suppose to be?

Comment: sorry @It_is_Chris i dont understand what you means ... I'm french so its doesnt help ...

Comment: @BryanOakley so how i can have this object . how i can recuperates the result of this event ? and why in the first code he have it and in the second he doesn't ??

Comment: okkk finally thats what @Sujay have said its x_root ! i have use dir(myobject) to find attribute of event ! thank you all

Comment: _"so how i can have this object "_ I don't know what you mean. What object are you talking about? You seem to be using an attribute that doesn't exist and isn't documented to exist. I don't know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set on line 9- 10 this:

```
GLOBAL_X = 0
GLOBAL_Y = 0
```

at line 242 this:

```
    def move_window(self, event):
        global GLOBAL_X, GLOBAL_Y
        x = win.winfo_pointerx() - GLOBAL_X
        y = win.winfo_pointery() - GLOBAL_Y
        win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x,y))

    def set_xy(self, event):
        global GLOBAL_X, GLOBAL_Y
        GLOBAL_X=   win.winfo_rootx()- event.widget.winfo_rootx() + event.x
        GLOBAL_Y =  win.winfo_rooty() - event.widget.winfo_rooty() + event.y
```

and don forget on line 448 this:

```
self.canvas_menu.bind("<Button-1>", self.set_xy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `event.x_name_of_the_window` with `event.x_root`.